# When does Rainbow's talent activate?

Tags: smash-up

Rainbow's talent says, "If you have played another minion here, draw a card."

Does this mean that any other minion I have played on the same base, regardless of which turn it was played on, allows me to activate the talent?  Or does this mean that when you play another minion on the same base after Rainbow is already on the base that you can activate the talent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggested reading:**

> Talent: If you have played another minion here *this turn*, draw a card.

This is a reasonable interpretation, limiting the time per turn to match the talent usage. This solves long-term memory issues (remembering what's been played, moved and removed) and also has the game effect of encouraging the player to continue playing minions in the same place, which suits the faction well.

This is also supported by [Barliman on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/19050107#19050107), who says that this was the intended functionality during playtesting.

Under this interpretation (and the RAW interpretation coming next), it doesn't matter if the qualifying minions were played and subsequently removed. It also won't work if minions have only been *moved* there.

---

**Read as written:**

As a talent, you can draw a card if you have *ever* played a minion other than that Rainbow on the base that Rainbow's currently on. This functions similarly to the above rule mechanically, but without the time limit and without a reason for the player to continue piling minions up.

---

**Alternate reading:**

> Talent: If you have another minion here, draw a card.

While this seems like a reasonable way to play the card, it would be odd that it wasn't worded like this. It's not too dissimilar, but it doesn't remotely match the way the card is written.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that thread but it was long and I didn't read to the end. :-(

Answer (score 0):

It means that f you play Rainbow's talent on a base, that already has one of your minions, you can draw a card.

There are a few problems:

1. If a minion has been played, but removed. For the sake of the text I would say, the talent also triggers. But this is harder to check (there is no physical minion left).
2. If you have played (or moved) another players minion on that base.

So in order to eliminate as much confusion and debate, I would interpret the text as: "If you play Rainbow on a base that already has one of your minions, draw a card."